# How to return column number instead in this array formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have this array formula:

```
={SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Source!K2:L13,F2)),0,1))}
```

The formula simply looks for all possible matches of words from *K2:L3* in a phrase in *F2*.
It returns the sum of how many words where found in *F2*.
What I need to do is return the column of the first range that contains a word that was found in *F2*.

For example I have this phrase in *F2* **Hello World, how are you?**
and I have a word **how** on let say *K2*, how can I return the column number of *K2* which is 11?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula

```
{=MIN(IFERROR((SEARCH(Source!K2:L13,F2))*0+COLUMN(K2:L13),20000))}
```

- `SEARCH` returns an Array of values where the word is found and Errors where the word is *not* found
- `COLUMN` returns an Array of the column numbers for each entry in the array
- `SEARCH(...)*0+COLUMN(...)` returns an Array of column numbers where the word is found and Errors where the word is *not* found
- `IFERROR(... , 20000)` returns an array, where any errors are replaced with `20000`, being a number > the max column number
- `MIN` return the minimum value in the array, being the first column where a word is found

Comment: wow, i've tried this and it works. care to explain it a little bit? I'd appreciate that.